# Utilizar método de autenticação costumizado firebase no VueJS

Tags: firebase, vue.js, autenticação, firestore

Estou tentando executar a autenticação do firestore através de um token costumizado (JWT). Entretanto estou enfrentando problemas para faze-lo. A documentação do firestore nos pede para instalar a biblioteca 'npm firebase-admin', baixar o json para autenticação e em seguida utilizar o código:

```
firebase.auth().signInWithCustomToken(token).catch(function(error) {
  // Handle Errors here.
  var errorCode = error.code;
  var errorMessage = error.message;
  // ...
});
```

Contudo não estou conseguindo fazer a autenticação, ele me passa o erro:

'signInWithCustomToken failed: First argument "token" must be a valid string.'

Alguem sabe o que pode ser?

Comment: Seu *token* é inválido https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens?hl=pt

Comment: Cheguei a ver essa pagina posteriormente, obrigado @ValdeirPsr